# Using vs code, how to get scala format to work and format my code?

Tags: scala, visual-studio-code, sbt, scalafmt, scala-metals

I have the scala format plugin in my multi project sbt repository.

```
addSbtPlugin("org.scalameta"    % "sbt-scalafmt"        % "2.3.2")
```

So in the sbt console if I run scalafmt it works fine

My build.sbt has:

```
scalafmtOnCompile := true
```

If I do a ~compile in sbt or just compile manually, it doesn't format my code during compilation.

What is wrong with my setup?

Also, running scalafmt works but it doesn't format my .scala files in /project like my Dependencies.scala file.  Why is it ignoring these files?

I am using VS Code with metals also as my IDE.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Scalafmt](https://scalameta.org/scalafmt/docs/installation.html#metals) seeems to work in VSC with Metals out-of-the-box on my machine

> Metals automatically uses Scalafmt to respond to formatting requests
>   from the editor, according to the configuration defined in
>   `.scalafmt.conf`... if there is no `.scalafmt.conf`, upon receiving the
>   first format request Metals will create the .scalafmt.conf file for
>   you.

Simply execute `Format Document` command from `Command Palette` in VSC and it should format according to `.scalafmt.conf.` If you would like to continuously format and compile on every source change and `scalafmtOnCompile` is not working, then try executing in sbt

```
~scalafmt;compile
```

however format on compile is [discouraged](https://scalameta.org/scalafmt/docs/installation.html#format-on-compile) as per documentation

> This option is discouraged since it messes up undo buffers in the
>   editor and it slows down compilation. It is recommended to use "format
>   on save" in the editor instead.

Answer (score 4):

In VS Code, if you go into `File -> Preferences - > Settings` and type in `editor.format`, you'll see a bunch of options.

Enable all of them and it metals should apply all of the changes according.